# Why is it that "I called for confirmation that ..." but "thank you for confirming that ..."?

Tags: gerunds

For example, it sounds natural to use the noun form in this sentence:
*This morning the hotel called for confirmation that I will stay there.*

But in this sentence it sounds better to use the gerund:
*Thank you for confirming that you will stay at our hotel.*

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In “I called for confirmation that ...”, confirmation is the object, however in “thank you for confirming that ...”, confirming is the verb. The sentence doesn't really work without both unless you want to be curt or efficient and just say "Thanks.", though this requires them to know you're referring to "for the confirmation".

There's no reason you can't use the noun to refer to the past tense, you just have to add in a different gerund as the verb you're performing on the object (confirmation), for example:

> Thank you for *providing* confirmation of your stay at the hotel.

> Thank you for *sending* confirmation of your stay at the hotel.

Answer (score 0):

*For* is a preposition and *confirm* is a verb. If any verb comes after any preposition, it comes in *-ing* form.